# How to implement table search/filter in react

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm quite new to react and I'm trying to implement search/filter in my react project but it's not working the way I want.

so I have two graphql api in the same component. The **GET_ALL_USERS** api fetches all the users which is supposed to be the default content of the table. The **searchResult** fetches users whose username or name match with string entered in the search if you want to search for a user. it's a backend search, not frontend search.

The result I want:
when I enter text in the search box and I hit the search button, I want to render the search result in the table, if the search returns zero users, I want to show 'no users with (entered string) found'. when I clear the search (could be a dedicated clear button), the table should then be cleared and show the default data (all users).

The result I am getting:
When I start typing in the search box, the search returns the result immediately while I've not even hit the search button. Also, if the text/string I search is not found in the db, the table renders all the users wihtout showing the user I searched is not found.
I also want to show the message 'no users found' in the table if there is no user in the db

Kindly check my code below.

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { GET_ALL_USERS, SEARCH_USERS } from "../graphql/Queries";
import { useState } from 'react';

const UsersTable = () => {

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

  const{ data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_ALL_USERS)
  const{ data: searchedData, error: searchedError, loading:searchedLoading } = useQuery(SEARCH_USERS, {
    variables: { name: search || null }
  })

  const searchedResult = searchedData ? searchedData.searchedUsers : []

  const masterData =(searchedResult && searchedResult.length > 0) ? searchedResult : data?.allUsers


 const handleSubmit = (e: any)=>{

 }


return(
   <div>
          /* search */
         <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder='Search for user' onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}/>
            <button onSubmit={handleSubmit}>Search</button> 
        </div>

        
       /*table*/
    <table className="w-full text-left">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Username
                </th>
                <th>
                    Age
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {masterData && masterData.map((user: any)=>{
            return (
              <tr key={user.id}>
                  <th>
                    {user.name}
                  </th>
                  <td>
                    {user.username}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {user.age}
                  </td>
              </tr>                                                 
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
    </table>

   </div>
)
}
```

I put the two api data, that's allUsers and the searchedUsers in the masterData because I don't want to create two different tables, one for searched results and one for allUsers show them conditionally

Comment: You have `onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}` which fires every time there is a change - like when you type a character.

Comment: @takendarkk do you suggest I remove the onchange from the input? I thought about that but if I do, how will I pass the text entered in the search box as a variable/parameter to the SEARCH_USER query?

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it by setting a state variable to return the search result and making use of the function.

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
const [searchedResult, setSearchedResult] = useState([])
const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
e.preventDefault()
setSearchedResult(searchedData.searchUser || [])}
const masterData = searchedResult.length > 0 ? searchedResult : data?.getAllUsers
```